# Test executable failing only when run in ctest

Tags: cmake, googletest, ctest

When I use the ctest interface to cmake (`add_test(...)`), and run the make target `make test`, several of my tests fail. When I run each test directly at the command line from the binary build folder, they all work.

What can I use to debug this?

Comment: Isn't it `add_test`?

Comment: @AntonioPerez - yes. edited

Answer (score 5):

To debug, you can first run `ctest` directly instead of `make test`.

Then you can add the `-V` option to `ctest` to get verbose output.

A third [neat trick from a cmake developer](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-January/026636.html) is to have ctest launch an xterm shell. So add

```
add_test(run_xterm xterm)
```

in your CMakeLists.txt file at the end. Then run `make test` and it will open up a xterm. Then see if you can replicate the test failing by running it from the xterm. If it does fail, then check your environment (i.e. run `env > xterm.env` from the xterm, then run it again `env > regular.env` from your normal session and diff the outputs).

---

I discovered that my tests were wired to look for external files passed on a relative path to the *top* of the binary cmake output folder (i.e. the one where you type `make test`).  However, when you run the test through ctest, the current working directory is the binary folder for that particular subdirectory, and the test failed.

In other words:

This worked

```
test/mytest
```

but this didn't work

```
cd test; ./mytest
```

I had to fixed the unit tests to use an absolute path to the configuration files it needed, instead of a path like `../../../testvector/foo.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [ctest](/questions/tagged/ctest) and [googletest](/questions/tagged/googletest) is that it assumes to run one command for each test case, whilst you will have potentially a lot of different test cases running in a single test executable. So when you use `add_test` with a Google Test executable, `CTest` reports one single failure whether actual number of failed test cases is 1 or 1000.

Since you say that running your test cases isolated makes them pass, my first suspicion is that your tests are somehow coupled. You can quickly check this by randomizing the test execution order using `--gtest_shuffle`, and see if you get the same failures.

I think the best approach to debug your failing test cases is not to use `CTest`, but just run the test executable using the [command line options](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_7_AdvancedGuide.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests) to filter the actual test cases getting run. I would start by running only the first test that fails together with the test run immediately before when the whole test suite is run.

Other useful tools to debug your test cases can be [`SCOPED_TRACE`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_7_AdvancedGuide.md#adding-traces-to-assertions) and extending your assertion messages with additional information.

Comment: I actually answered my own question, but your answer will help others. I have had the problem you mentioned, where previous tests would alter the program state and cause subsequent tests to fail, even though each test run separately would pass -- this was because I had bad UB (Undefined Behavior) code that was sensitive to random memory contents...